# Very fast search for specific characters in Java

Tags: java, performance, search, character

this probably seems like a bit of a silly question.. And maybe it is. But I have a function which I use very frequently and wanted an opinion on if this is the fastest way to do the job. The function is used so many times that any speed increase would actually be noticeable. All it does is check if a character is a nucleotide (ie: if a char is 'A', 'T', 'C', or 'G'.

```
private static boolean isValidNucleotide(char nucleotide) {
    nucleotide = Character.toUpperCase(nucleotide);
    if(nucleotide == 'A') return true; 
    if(nucleotide == 'T') return true;
    if(nucleotide == 'C') return true;
    if(nucleotide == 'G') return true;
    return false;
}
```

Is this the fastest way to accomplish the job? Or do you think it's worth implementing some kind of index/map/something else (possibly to perform the comparison outside of a function and just copy this text to several spots in the code)? I'm really not an expert on this kind of thing in Java.

Comment: Step back a bit and re-examine the actual _problem_ rather than your solution. It may actually be faster to do this a totally different way such as, for example, restricting the user input up front, or checking the entire nucleotide sequence early so that there's no repeated checks later on. There could even be a case to be made for (if you care more about speed than validity) not checking at all.

Comment: @paxdiablo thanks for the suggestions. I did accept an answer but these comments definitely deserve consideration. I do have to validate, but there may be a way to restrict the input earlier on in the chain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most fastest (but least memory efficient still 255 bytes not bad!) would be like this:

```
/* this is static member of class */
static boolean map[] = new boolean[256];
static {
    for(int j = 0; j < map.length; j++)
        map[j] = false;
    /* map your required values true here */ 
    map['A'] = true;
    map['T'] = true;
    map['C'] = true;
    map['G'] = true;
    /* make small letter here too */
    map['a'] = true;
    map['t'] = true;
    map['c'] = true;
    map['g'] = true;
}
```

Then make a function like this:

```
private static boolean isValidNucleotide(char nucleotide) {
    /* complexity is just one access to array */
    return map[nucleotide];
}
```

As said by @paxdiablo, in java char is 2 bytes not 1 bytes but you characters are within this range. By simply changing `return map[nucleotide];` to `return map[0x00ff & nucleotide];` should work.

You can also change size of map to `65536` to be on safe side and avoid any sort of errors. `boolean map = new boolean[65536]`

Comment: What happens if you get a character _above_ 255? Isn't Java inherently Unicode?

Comment: This seems to be the way. I did a test similar to what iTech did. Impressive!

Comment: You should also change that to 256 by the way, giving you indexes 0..255.

Comment: So in fact, what happens if nucleotide is above 255 is that you get an exception!  Or if you mask it, you may get the wrong answer ... which is even worse.

Comment: @StephenC Yes you are right! I was thinking wrong way. I guess only option left is to make 255 to 2^16 - 1 :)

Comment: @StephenC So to be safe, should I be increasing the number beyond 256? Memory is not really a concern so much as speed. But getting the correct answer is certainly a concern.

Comment: @ShivamKalra Ah I see. I wonder if that would have an impact on the speed you were able to achieve there.

Comment: No, I tested it and it did not reduce the speed. Thanks so much for your help everyone!

Comment: @MementoMori - you need to make a judgement call.  Are characters larger than 255 actually possible in your application?  If so you should start with an explicit test for `nucleotide > some value`.  (And if the JIT compiler is really smart, it will realize that the implicit test for array index out of range won't be necessary ...)

Answer (score 3):

You can try a `switch-case`, which is usually implemented as a table lookup for small switches:

```
switch(nucleotide) {
case 'A':
case 'T':
case 'C':
case 'G':
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Note that the JVM's JIT will probably make your `if`-based code pretty quick if it gets called often enough.

Comment: Interesting, yeah I was wondering if the JVM would make those kinds of optimizations on its own. This looks solid though. I'll try a test and see what it does to the run-time.

Comment: You can also try replacing the `toUpperCase` call by adding the lowercase letters to the `switch`.

Comment: Having checked, the accepted answer is faster than this one on my machine. This answer is good too though, as it is also fast and is clearer in its intent, meaning it might get more benefit from future optimizations to the JRE.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `Character.toUpperCase` and check for both capital and small cases it will speed up your function significantly.

```
private static boolean isValidNucleotide(char nucleotide) {       
    if(nucleotide == 'A' || nucleotide == 'a') return true; 
    // Rest of your conditions

    return false;
}
```

I made a small test with your original function and it took on average `80 ms` to execute`10000000 times` but when I removed `Character.toUpperCase()` and checked explicitly for both cases it took `40 ms` only, which is significant improvement.

**Edit:**

Using the `Map` solution suggested by @Shivam Kalra took only `11 ms` on average !

Comment: Try changing `switch (nucleotide)` to `switch ((byte) nucleotide)`

Comment: I tried but it did not affect the performance, it took `40 ms` as well

Comment: the map solution is faster because it is skimping on some range checking.  It only works if you can assume that the input characters are all less than 256.

Comment: (My idea was that maybe the JIT compiler could be convinced to use a larger switch table and avoid some "unnecessary" range testing.  That would have made it faster.)

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried, but you can try and see the performance using Regex